# n1ql primary scan performance

Tags: couchbase, sql++

my document is as follow,

```
{
  "date": "1970-02-19",
  “uid”: 2345
  “profile": [
    "Profile Text, Profile Text, Profile Text, Profile Text, Profile Text",
    "Profile Text,  Profile Text,  Profile Text,  Profile Text,  Profile Text",
    "Profile Text,  Profile Text,  Profile Text,  Profile Text,  Profile Text"
  ],
  “channel_a”: {
    "reach": 915157,
     "likes": 6.39,
     "shares": 8.15,
     "followergrowth": 6.89
  },
  “channel_b”: {
    "reach": 894888,
    "response": 8.64,
    "influence": 7.03,
    "reject": 5.09
  },
  “channel_c” {
    "reach": 396938
  }
}
```

The document key is composed of the document type, user id (a number), and date. e.g. channels:9999:2015-12-31. I want to build a query to return a list of top 10 users who have the highest engagement rate for a specific channel in a given calendar month. The criteria can vary depending on the channel, and requirements.

The above query plan uses the primary index scan, it took almost a minute to complete. The qualified dataset is around 1.3K rows, but this could increase to 5K rows. Is there any mechanism on Couchbase I can use in order to obtain better performance? also, I am looking for a scalable solution as the data size grows.

```
select 
    s. uid,
    sum(s.channel_c.reach) channel_c_Reach,
    sum(s.channel_b.reach) channel_b_Reach,
    sum(s.channel_a.likes) channel_a_Likes
FROM channels s
where meta().id like ‘channels:%:2016-05-%’
group by s.uid
ORDER BY sum(s.channel_a.likes) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

If your query is using the primary index, there is a lot you can improve. The key thing is to create several indexes to support your query.

Check out this article with talks about how to create indexes for group bys:
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/groupby-aggregate-performance.html

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON channels(uid, date, channel_a.likes, channel_c.reach, channel_b.reach)
WHERE meta().id like "channels:%";
SELECT
    s.uid,
    sum(s.channel_c.reach) channel_c_Reach,
    sum(s.channel_b.reach) channel_b_Reach,
    sum(s.channel_a.likes) channel_a_Likes
FROM channels s
WHERE meta(s).id like "channels:%" AND s.uid IS NOT NULL AND s.date LIKE "2016-05-%"
group by s.uid
ORDER BY sum(s.channel_a.likes) DESC
LIMIT 10 ;
```

Also Checkout https://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-index-grouping-aggregation-couchbase-n1ql-query/

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the index scan, as you have surmised in your question's title.  There are a couple of options that you can experiment to improve the query performance.

1. The filter [ like 'channels:%:2015-05-%' ] would force a scan of the
   entire index to generate the groups, then fetch the data for the
   aggregation. This is likely where most of the time is spent, so addressing this issue is key.  Do you have an option to redesign the document key
   to increase the selectivity, i.e. by putting the 'date' component
   before the 'user id'?   It should run a lot faster if you could
   change it to [ like ‘channels:2016-05-%’]
2. If you are on Couchbase v6.0, you could enable Couchbase Analytics service in your setup.
    https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/analytics/primer-beer.html.
   Couchbase Analytics uses **SQL++**, aka. N1QL for Couchbase Analytics.
   That means you can use the same query, and point it to the Analytics
   service. It is designed to help with queries that need access to a
   large number of documents, leveraging parallel processing
   algorithms.

Option 1 would be the most efficient way to solve this, and the **SQL++ Couchbase Analytics** should give you a significant improvement without any changes.